# hbase bulk load failed for "[LoadIncrementalHFiles-0] client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception"

Tags: hbase, bulk-load

when I use hbase bulk load on s3 with the follows command:
1. create 'personas' ,{NAME => 'bs'},{NAME => 'ml',},SPLITS => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f']
2. hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=, -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,bs:game_id_1,bs:data_desc_1,bs:register_time_1,bs:uid_1,bs:last_load_1,bs:load_status_1,bs:max_step_1,bs:tutorial_times_1,bs:initial_lev_1,bs:area_id_1,bs:game_id_2,bs:data_desc_2,bs:register_time_2,bs:uid_2,bs:last_load_2,bs:load_status_2,bs:max_step_2,bs:tutorial_times_2,bs:initial_lev_2,bs:area_id_2,bs:game_id_3,bs:data_desc_3,bs:register_time_3,bs:uid_3,bs:last_load_3,bs:load_status_3,bs:max_step_3,bs:tutorial_times_3,bs:initial_lev_3,bs:area_id_3,bs:game_id_4,bs:data_desc_4,bs:register_time_4,bs:uid_4,bs:last_load_4,bs:load_status_4,bs:max_step_4,bs:tutorial_times_4,bs:initial_lev_4,bs:area_id_4,bs:game_id_5,bs:data_desc_5,bs:register_time_5,bs:uid_5,bs:last_load_5,bs:load_status_5,bs:max_step_5,bs:tutorial_times_5,bs:initial_lev_5,bs:area_id_5,bs:game_id_6,bs:data_desc_6,bs:register_time_6,bs:uid_6,bs:last_load_6,bs:load_status_6,bs:max_step_6,bs:tutorial_times_6,bs:initial_lev_6,bs:area_id_6,bs:game_id_7,bs:data_desc_7,bs:register_time_7,bs:uid_7,bs:last_load_7,bs:load_status_7,bs:max_step_7,bs:tutorial_times_7,bs:initial_lev_7,bs:area_id_7,bs:game_id_8,bs:data_desc_8,bs:register_time_8,bs:uid_8,bs:last_load_8,bs:load_status_8,bs:max_step_8,bs:tutorial_times_8,bs:initial_lev_8,bs:area_id_8,bs:game_id_9,bs:data_desc_9,bs:register_time_9,bs:uid_9,bs:last_load_9,bs:load_status_9,bs:max_step_9,bs:tutorial_times_9,bs:initial_lev_9,bs:area_id_9,bs:game_id_10,bs:data_desc_10,bs:register_time_10,bs:uid_10,bs:last_load_10,bs:load_status_10,bs:max_step_10,bs:tutorial_times_10,bs:initial_lev_10,bs:area_id_10,ml:game_id_11,ml:data_desc_11,ml:register_time_11,ml:uid_11,ml:last_load_11,ml:load_status_11,ml:max_step_11,ml:tutorial_times_11,ml:initial_lev_11,ml:area_id_11,ml:game_id_12,ml:data_desc_12,ml:register_time_12,ml:uid_12,ml:last_load_12,ml:load_status_12,ml:max_step_12,ml:tutorial_times_12,ml:initial_lev_12,ml:area_id_12,ml:game_id_13,ml:data_desc_13,ml:register_time_13,ml:uid_13,ml:last_load_13,ml:load_status_13,ml:max_step_13,ml:tutorial_times_13,ml:initial_lev_13,ml:area_id_13,ml:game_id_14,ml:data_desc_14,ml:register_time_14,ml:uid_14,ml:last_load_14,ml:load_status_14,ml:max_step_14,ml:tutorial_times_14,ml:initial_lev_14,ml:area_id_14,ml:game_id_15,ml:data_desc_15,ml:register_time_15,ml:uid_15,ml:last_load_15,ml:load_status_15,ml:max_step_15,ml:tutorial_times_15,ml:initial_lev_15,ml:area_id_15,ml:game_id_16,ml:data_desc_16,ml:register_time_16,ml:uid_16,ml:last_load_16,ml:load_status_16,ml:max_step_16,ml:tutorial_times_16,ml:initial_lev_16,ml:area_id_16,ml:game_id_17,ml:data_desc_17,ml:register_time_17,ml:uid_17,ml:last_load_17,ml:load_status_17,ml:max_step_17,ml:tutorial_times_17,ml:initial_lev_17,ml:area_id_17,ml:game_id_18,ml:data_desc_18,ml:register_time_18,ml:uid_18,ml:last_load_18,ml:load_status_18,ml:max_step_18,ml:tutorial_times_18,ml:initial_lev_18,ml:area_id_18,ml:game_id_19,ml:data_desc_19,ml:register_time_19,ml:uid_19,ml:last_load_19,ml:load_status_19,ml:max_step_19,ml:tutorial_times_19,ml:initial_lev_19,ml:area_id_19,ml:game_id_20,ml:data_desc_20,ml:register_time_20,ml:uid_20,ml:last_load_20,ml:load_status_20,ml:max_step_20,ml:tutorial_times_20,ml:initial_lev_20,ml:area_id_20  -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=s3://allen-spark-test/hfile/user_400w0000 personas s3://architecture_bucket/user_4000w/0000_part_00 -Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=true
3.hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles s3://allen-spark-test/hfile/user_400w0000/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1487298628615_0001_r_000000_0 personas

at step 3, fired such errors over and over again , are there any one can tell me how to fix this problem, thanks in advance.

2017-02-17 05:46:48,050 INFO  [LoadIncrementalHFiles-0] mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Trying to load hfile=s3://allen-spark-test/hfile/user_400w0000/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1487298628615_0001_r_000000_0/ml/f0bd47760d924d8892b72aa574150b19 first=58_9999_1126028772568700 last=9_9999_999936924
2017-02-17 05:46:48,161 INFO  [LoadIncrementalHFiles-1] mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Trying to load hfile=s3://allen-spark-test/hfile/user_400w0000/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1487298628615_0001_r_000000_0/ml/78256ffc03344532971ede95be892ce4 first=1_9999_100002476412552 last=58_9999_1126028772568574
2017-02-17 05:58:26,647 INFO  [LoadIncrementalHFiles-0] client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=698473 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row '' on table 'personas' at region=personas,,1487300932958.3cc86282fc8b90516c400ab447234ab7., hostname=ip-10-16-212-143.ec2.internal,16020,1487298695908, seqNum=2
2017-02-17 05:59:36,665 INFO  [LoadIncrementalHFiles-0] client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=768492 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row '' on table 'personas' at region=personas,,1487300932958.3cc86282fc8b90516c400ab447234ab7., hostname=ip-10-16-212-143.ec2.internal,16020,1487298695908, seqNum=2
2017-02-17 06:00:56,803 INFO  [LoadIncrementalHFiles-0] client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=12, retries=35, started=848630 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row '' on table 'personas' at region=personas,,1487300932958.3cc86282fc8b90516c400ab447234ab7., hostname=ip-10-16-212-143.ec2.internal,16020,1487298695908, seqNum=2
2017-02-17 06:02:16,930 INFO  [LoadIncrementalHFiles-0] client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=13, retries=35, started=928757 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row '' on table 'personas' at region=personas,,1487300932958.3cc86282fc8b90516c400ab447234ab7., hostname=ip-10-16-212-143.ec2.internal,16020,1487298695908, seqNum=2
2017-02-17 06:03:37,066 INFO  [LoadIncrementalHFiles-0] client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=14, retries=35, started=1008892 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row '' on table 'personas' at region=personas,,1487300932958.3cc86282fc8b90516c400ab447234ab7., hostname=ip-10-16-212-143.ec2.internal,16020,1487298695908, seqNum=2

Comment: Did you ever solve this? am running into a similar issue

Comment: i remember that i upgrade the aws ec2 instance then this issue didn't fired again.

Comment: Gotcha -- thanks Allen